# Latest version of Apache Commons Lang 3

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang3

I'm reading the API for StringUtils, and it refers to the method [truncate](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#truncate(java.lang.String,%20int)), since API 3.5. But, the latest version is 3.4. according to the apache commons site. I don't even see a 3.5 development branch on their [git](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/branches) or in maven central. What is the latest version?

Comment: 3.5 is not published to maven yet. Why your are not using 3.4?

Comment: Well, that method is in the master branch, so I don't see why you can't use it, despite what the documentation says.

Comment: @dit I didn't say what version I was using. I can't use it becuase i'm pulling my dependencies from maven, which doesn't have 3.5 on there yet.

Answer (score 1):

As of time of this answer, 3.4 is the latest stable version.  Version 3.5 is actually 3.5-SNAPSHOT.  You can see that indicated in top right of the website, and the javadoc is generated off the source tree. You can see that master branch is currently set to 3.5-SNAPSHOT here:

- https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

3.5 Should be the latest now, last published back in October 2016.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
   <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```